# How can I get HDFS free space in Java code?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

To get available free space in HDFS, I can use following command:

```
hadoop fs -df /
```

But I need to access it using Java code. The Hadoop Filesystem API doesn't seem to give free hdfs space.

I could find the java equivalent of df command but was not able to understand how to use it.

Can anyone plese help?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

After studying the code of how the command works I found out that it uses Hadoop FileSystem API to fetch an `FsStatus` object. This object gives used and free hdfs space.

The code to fetch this can be:

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

    Path path = new Path("/");
    long used = fs.getStatus(path).getUsed();
    long available = fs.getStatus(path).getRemaining();
```